# pandas dictionary to list of dictionary key/values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to perform list comprehension with nested list of dictionary from data-frame and I get this after some tryouts. Is there pandas functionality that I might be missing than using for loops?

```
file = ['a.txt','a.txt','b.txt','c.txt']
year = ['2016','2017','2016','2018']
paper = ['Biology','Biology','Math','English']
name = ['Ann,Matt','Maya','Rob',np.nan]

df = pd.DataFrame({
                'file':file,
                'year':year,
                'paper':paper,
                'name':name
            })
df


dfd = df.to_dict('index')
dfd
>>>
{0: {'file': 'a.txt', 'year': '2016', 'paper': 'Biology', 'name': 'Ann,Matt'},
 1: {'file': 'a.txt', 'year': '2017', 'paper': 'Biology', 'name': 'Maya'},
 2: {'file': 'b.txt', 'year': '2016', 'paper': 'Math', 'name': 'Rob'},
 3: {'file': 'c.txt', 'year': '2018', 'paper': 'English', 'name': nan}}
```

Tried:

```
d = []
for i in dfd.items():
    d.append(i)

>>>
[(0,
  {'file': 'a.txt', 'year': '2016', 'paper': 'Biology', 'name': 'Ann,Matt'}),
 (1, {'file': 'a.txt', 'year': '2017', 'paper': 'Biology', 'name': 'Maya'}),
 (2, {'file': 'b.txt', 'year': '2016', 'paper': 'Math', 'name': 'Rob'}),
 (3, {'file': 'c.txt', 'year': '2018', 'paper': 'English', 'name': nan})]
```

I am trying to get it like this: its in tuple format.

```
[{'file': 'a.txt', 'year': '2016', 'paper': 'Biology', 'name': 'Ann,Matt'},
 {'file': 'a.txt', 'year': '2017', 'paper': 'Biology', 'name': 'Maya'},
 {'file': 'b.txt', 'year': '2016', 'paper': 'Math', 'name': 'Rob'},
 {'file': 'c.txt', 'year': '2018', 'paper': 'English', 'name': nan}]
```

Comment: Use `df.to_dict('records')`, this will give you the required result.

Comment: Thanks! Should have tried that before

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it correct above. You can use dfd.items() to iterate over both the keys and values at once of your dfd dict. Then you can ignore the key part of the tuple and just add the value to the list comprehension like this:

```
d = [v for k,v in dfd.items()]
```

Just tested that with the data and it gives the output you want